# Retrieving an object list of IEnumerable adding a new object to it then setting a dropdown datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

My DAL function GetProducts() returns a list of IEnumerable product. How would I take this list in my code behind and add a new product item to it? I believe I can't since it is an IEnumerable. My first instinct was to do the following but it isn't working:

```
        List<Product> productList = ProductDAL.GetProducts();
        // add new item
        Product newProduct = new Product
        {
            Id = 1,
            ProductName = Test Product"
        };
        productList.Add(newProduct);

        // Then set dropdownlist datasource
```

Comment: `My DAL function GetProducts() returns a list of IEnumerable` That's not what your code shows.  It shows it returning a `List<Product>`.  When you say it isn't working, what, specifically, isn't working about it.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the specific line of code that is erroring is when I am trying to set productList. Intellisense says: Cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable<Product> to List<Product>

Comment: This code should work. Please provide some more information about "Isn't working".

Comment: Not sure why everyone is hating on this post. C# intellisense is telling me that I can't set List<Product> to an IEnumerable<Product>. Which is what I am trying to do in my first line of code.

Comment: Sorry about this post guys. All of my code was correct I just had to build my DAL. For whatever reason it didn't think my function was returning as .ToList().

Answer (score 2):

If your `GetProducts()` is returning an `IEnumerable`, you could try calling `ToList()` method which will return list. There you could add the item into it:

```
List<Product> productList = ProductDAL.GetProducts().ToList();
Product newProduct = new Product
{
    Id = 1,
    ProductName = "Test Product"
};
productList.Add(newProduct);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Uggh I am so sorry about this post guys. I checked my DAL function and the linq query is returning .ToList(). I just had to build my DAL and the way my code is works.